# Get token to call post to firebase database in react-native

Tags: firebase, api, react-native, post

I have a firebase database and i need to do a classic post call, but i have a problem with token.

For example, in firebase for get user i use `app().auth().currentUser.uid`,
for a classic get list i use `app().firestore().collection('prizes')` and it work.

so, to get user token i do `app().auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`
and for post i do

```js
export function postData(endpoint: string, data: any, token) {
  return fetchJson(ENDPOINT_API + endpoint}, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token ? token : USER_TOKEN}`,
    },
  })
}
```

and result is

> {"error":"Token invalid","message":"Cannot destructure property `type` of 'undefined' or 'null'."}

the token comes back to me, but I don't know if it's the correct way

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```js
Authorization: `Bearer ${token ? token : USER_TOKEN}`,
```

Replace it by:

```js
'Authorization': `Bearer ${token ? token : USER_TOKEN}`,
```

Comment: This works for me  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+{token ? token : USER_TOKEN},